# Как этот char преобразовать в String

Tags: java, строки, char, byte, com-port

```
byte[] newData = new byte[comPort.bytesAvailable()];
int numRead = comPort.readBytes(newData, newData.length);
for (int i = 0; i < newData.length; ++i) {
 System.out.print((char) newData[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если нужно просто преобразовать массив байт в строку, то можно попробовать так:

```
byte[] rawdata = "Some Data".getBytes();

try {
    String d = new String(rawdata, "UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Массив байт в строку через BigInteger:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

/**
 *
 * @author vvm
 */
public class ByteToString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] newData = new byte[]{0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34};
        String str = new BigInteger(1, newData).toString(16);
        System.out.println("str = " + str);
    }
}
```

Но это не оптимальный вариант, так как получается лишняя упаковка - распаковка.

Еще информация [>>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88838/how-to-convert-strings-to-and-from-utf8-byte-arrays-in-java/88863#88863)